# Dynamic Content into mail() $message

Tags: php

I'm just trying to put together a simple HTML email confirming an order to my database.

My $message looks a little like:

```
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Whatever</title>
</head>
<body>

etc etc
</body>
</html>
";
```

What i want to do within the $message HTML is make a call to my database which will return rows something like:

```
$emailinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysql_error());
```

To which i can then use in my $message along the lines of:

```
<p><?php echo $emailinfo['customername'];?></p>
```

There's nothing wrong with my query or my tables etc, the problem i'm having and need help with is getting the results from mysql_fetch_assoc into my $message html.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: ...you mean like `$message = 'Hello '.$emailinfo['customername'].'!';`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**Example:**

```
$message = <<<END
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Whatever</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>{$emailinfo['customername']}</p>
  </body>
</html>
END;
```

There are several other ways to achieve this. For more information, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php.

**Loop example:**

```
<?php

while ( $emailinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
  // The "END;" must be at the start of the line (e.g. no white spaces before it).
  $message = <<<END
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Whatever</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>{$emailinfo['customername']}</p>
      </body>
    </html>
END;

  echo $message;
}
```

Comment: Mmm, that looks to have done the trick Francois, thank you so much, i've been tearing my hair out! :)

Comment: I'd also like to run through a while loop within the $message Francios, can you help with how that syntax fits within $message? Normally i'd use do { .... } while ($emailinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); but i don't know how to work it in so its recognised as php

Comment: You'll want `$message = ...` in your loop.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work Francois, outside of $message its fine, but it only seems to echo out the first row from the results in the email.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick Francois. I've started a new question on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574316/running-a-loop-through-message-in-mail Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated :)